# Algebraically interpreting polymorphism

Tags: haskell, types

So I understand the basic algebraic interpretation of types:

```
Either a b ~ a + b
(a, b) ~ a * b
a -> b ~ b^a
()   ~ 1
Void ~ 0 -- from Data.Void
```

... and that these relations are true for concrete types, like `Bool`, as opposed to polymorphic types like `a`.  I also know how to translate type signatures with polymorphic types into their concrete type representations by just translating the Church encoding according to the following isomorphism:

```
(forall r . (a -> r) -> r) ~ a
```

So if I have:

```
id :: forall a . a -> a
```

I know that it does not mean `id ~ a^a`, but it actually means:

```
id :: forall a . (() -> a) -> a
id ~ ()
   ~ 1
```

Similarly:

```
pair :: forall r . (a -> b -> r) -> r
pair ~ ((a, b) -> r) - > r
     ~ (a, b)
     ~ a * b
```

Which brings me to my question.  What is the "algebraic" interpretation of this rule:

```
(forall r . (a -> r) -> r) ~ a
```

For every concrete type isomorphism I can point to an equivalent algebraic rule, such as:

```
(a, (b, c)) ~ ((a, b), c)
a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c

a -> (b -> c) ~ (a, b) -> c
(c^b)^a = c^(b * a)
```

But I don't understand the algebraic equality that is analogous to:

```
(forall r . (a -> r) -> r) ~ a
```

Comment: Two more to think about: `forall r. (r -> a, r) ~ a` and `forall r s. (a -> (r, s)) -> (r, s) ~ a*a`. Also, Brent Yorgey did a series of blogposts about this: http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/enumerating-linear-inhabitants/

Comment: You've discovered that a bunch of equations in types correspond to rules of "high school algebra" (HSA). But there's no reason to expect all type equations to come from high school algebra. The Yoneda lemma (or at least the specialisation of it you've mentioned) is a new algebraic law. Just add it to the high school rules and carry on reasoning. Here's an example of useful stuff you can derive using HSA+Yoneda: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/11/memoizing-polymorphic-functions-with.html

Comment: @user207442 Thanks, and that link is pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is the famous [**Yoneda lemma**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) for the identity functor.

Check [this](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/11/yoneda-lemma.html) post for a readable introduction, and any category theory textbook for more.

Briefly, given `f :: forall r. (a -> r) -> r` you can apply `f id` to get an `a`, and conversely, given `x :: a` you can take `($x)` to get `forall r. (a -> r) -> r`.

These operations are mutually inverse. Proof:

Obviously `($x) id == x`. I will show that

`($(f id)) == f`,

since functions are equal when they are equal on all arguments, let's take `x :: a -> r` and show that

`($(f id)) x == f x` i.e.

`x (f id) == f x`.

Since `f` is polymorphic, it works as a natural transformation; this is the naturality diagram for `f`:

```
               f_A
     Hom(A, A)  →  A
(x.)      ↓        ↓ x
     Hom(A, R)  →  R
               f_R
```

So `x . f == f . (x.)`.

Plugging identity, `(x . f) id == f x`. QED

Comment: This is very insightful and I learned a lot from this.  Technically it does not answer my question, but it's fascinating enough that if I don't get a more specific answer I will accept this anyway after a couple of days.  However, the answer I'm really looking for is what is the algebraic equation that "forall r . (r -> a) -> a ~ a" translates into, if any.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez You did get the answer: the equation it corresponds to is the statement of the Yoneda lemma! You may be unsettled that it's not a set-based equation like the other equations you suggested, but it turns out there *is* no set-theoretic model for forall types; you really need to step out into the wider world of category theory to get your correspondence.

Answer (score 17):

(Rewritten for clarity)

There seem to be two parts to your question. One is implied and is asking what the algebraic interpretation of `forall` is, and the other is asking about the cont/Yoneda transformation, which sdcvvc's answer already covered pretty well.

I'll try to address the algebraic interpretation of `forall` for you. You mention that `A -> B` is `B^A` but I'd like to take that a step further and expand it out to `B * B * B * ... * B` (`|A|` times). Although we do have exponentiation as a notation for repeated multiplication like that, there's a more flexible notation, `∏` (uppercase Pi) representing arbitrary indexed products. There are two components to a Pi: the range of values we want to multiply over, and the expression that we're multiplying out. For example, at the value level, you might express the factorial function as `fact i = ∏ [1..i] (λx -> x)`.

Going back to the world of types, we can view the exponentiation operator in the `A -> B ~ B^A` correspondence as a Pi: `B^A ~ ∏ A (λ_ -> B)`. This says that we're defining an `A`-ary product of `B`s, such that the `B`s cannot depend on the particular `A` we've chosen. Sure, it's equivalent to plain exponentiation, but it lets us move up to cases in which there is a dependence.

In the most general case, we get dependent types, like what you see in Agda or Coq: in Agda syntax, `replicate : Bool -> ((n : Nat) -> Vec Bool n)` is one possible application of a Pi type, which could be expressed more explicitly as `replicate : Bool -> ∏ Nat (Vec Bool)`, or further as `replicate : ∏ Bool (λ_ -> ∏ Nat (Vec Bool))`.

Note that as you might expect from the underlying algebra, you can fuse both of the `∏`s in the definition of `replicate` above into a single `∏` ranging over the cartesian product of the domains: `∏ Bool (\_ -> ∏ Nat (Vec Bool))` is equivalent to `∏ (Bool, Nat) (λ(_, n) -> Vec Bool n)` just like it would be at the "value level". This is simply uncurrying from the perspective of type theory.

I do realize your question was about polymorphism, so I'll stop going on about dependent types, but they are relevant: `forall` in Haskell is roughly equivalent to a `∏` with a domain over the type (kind) of types, `*`. Indeed, the function-like behavior of polymorphism can be observed directly in GHC core, which types them as capital lambdas (Λ). As such, a polymorphic type like `forall a. a -> a` is actually just `∏ * (Λ a -> (a -> a))` (using the Λ notation now that we distinguish between types and values), which can be expanded out to the infinite product `(Bool -> Bool, Int -> Int, () -> (), (Int -> Bool) -> (Int -> Bool), ...)` for every possible type. Instantiation of the type variable is simply projecting out the suitable element from the `*`-ary product (or applying the type function).

Now, for the big piece I missed in my original version of this answer: parametricity. Parametricity can be described in several different ways, but none of the ones I know of (viewing types as relations, or (di)naturality in category theory) really has a very algebraic interpretation. For our purposes, though, it boils down to something fairly simple: you can't pattern-match on `*`. I know that GHC lets you do that at the type level with type families, but you can only cover a finite chunk of `*` when doing that, so there are necessarily always points at which your type family is undefined.

What this means, from the point of view of polymorphism, is that any type function `F` we write in `∏ * F` must either be constant (i.e., completely ignore the type it was polymorphic over) or pass the type through unchanged. Thus, `∏ * (Λ _ -> B)` is valid because it ignores its argument, and corresponds to `forall a. B`. The other case is something like `∏ * (Λ x -> Maybe x)`, which corresponds to `forall a. Maybe a`, which doesn't ignore the type argument, but only "passes it through". As such, a `∏ A` that has an irrelevant domain `A` (such as when `A = *`) can be seen as more of an `A`-ary indexed *intersection* (picking the common elements across all instantiations of the index), rather than a product.

Crucially, at the value level, the rules of parametricity prevent any funny behavior that might suggest the types are larger than they really are. Because we don't have typecase, we can't construct a value of type `forall a. B` that does something different based on what `a` was instantiated to. Thus, although the type is technically a function `* -> B`, it is *always* a constant function, and is thus equivalent to a single value of `B`. Using the `∏` interpretation, it is indeed equivalent to an infinite `*`-ary product of `B`s, but those `B` values must always be identical, so the infinite product is effectively as big as a single `B`.

Similarly, although `∏ * (Λ x -> (x -> x))` (a.k.a., `forall a. a -> a`) is technically equivalent to an infinite product of functions, none of those functions can inspect the type, so all are constrained to only return their input value and not do any funny business like `(+1) : Int -> Int` when instantiated to `Int`. Because there is only one (assuming a total language) function that can't inspect the type of its argument but must return a value of that same type, the infinite product is thus just as large as a single value.

Now, about your direct question on `(forall r . (a -> r) -> r) ~ a`. First, let's express your `~` operator more formally. It's really isomorphism, so we need two functions going back and forth, and an argument that they're inverses.

```
data Iso a b = Iso 
  { to   :: a -> b
  , from :: b -> a
  -- proof1 :: forall x. to (from x) == x
  -- proof2 :: forall x. from (to x) == x
  }
```

and now we express your original question in more formal terms. Your question amounts to constructing a term of the following (impredicative, so GHC has trouble with it, but we'll survive) type:

```
forall a. Iso (forall r. (a -> r) -> r) a
```

Which, using my earlier terminology, amounts to `∏ * (Λ a -> Iso (∏ * (Λ r -> ((a -> r) -> r))) a)`. Once again we have an infinite product that can't inspect its type argument. By handwaving, we can argue that the only possible values considering the parametricity rules (the other two proofs are respected automatically) for `to` and `from` are `($ id)` and `flip id`.

If this feels unsatisfying, it's probably because the algebraic interpretation of `forall` didn't really add anything to the proof. It's really just plain old type theory, but I hope I was able to provide something that feels a little less categorical than the Yoneda form of it. It's worth noting that we don't actually need to use parametricity to write `proof1` and `proof2` above, though. Parametricity only enters the picture when we want to state that `($ id)` and `flip id` are our only options for `to` and `from` (which we can't prove in Agda or Coq, for that reason).

Comment: But parametricity changes it very much! For example `forall a. B` is equivalent to `B` due to parametricity, but they would not be equivalent if you interpreted forall as an infinite product of B with itself!

Comment: The problem with this is that the product `(Int -> Int, Bool -> Bool, ...)` is not isomorphic (in the category theory sense) to `forall a . a -> a`.  The counter example is if I construct a product where one element of the product is specialized to its type, such as `((+1), id, id, ...)`.  `id` evalutes to `1` in the type algebra precisely because it has exactly one implementation, whereas the product has infinitely many implementations, and therefore cannot possibly be isomorphic to the set of `id` implementations.

Comment: The terminology can be a bit confusing: ∏ types are called either dependent functions _or_ products and Σ are dependent products _or_ pairs. From type theory point of view, the former makes more sense - ∏ generalizes function and Σ pairs. However, ∏x:ℕ.P(x) corresponds to (∀x∊ℕ) P(x) and universal qualifiction can be viewed as infinite conjunction P(0) ∧ P(1) ∧ ... and that's where you get the name "product"; Σx:ℕ.P(x) ~ (∃x∊ℕ) P(x) which can be viewed as P(0) ∨ P(1) ∨ ... and thus "sum". From logic point of view, it's the latter name.

Comment: Parametricity does complicate things slightly, but does not change the basic idea. Gabriel's example can't be constructed because of parametricity, simply because you have no way of knowing, when constructing that infinite product term, that you have an `Int` (because you don't have typecase).

Vitus: I've never heard of Σ referred to as a dependent product. It's usually called either a dependent sum or a dependent pair, in my experience.

Comment: Rotsor: for the same reason, it is still an infinite product of `B` values, but they must all be the same (and thus isomorphic to a single `B`) because they can't observe what `a` was.

Comment: @copumpkin: Oh, I meant "dependent pair _or_ sum". Too late to edit now.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to cover the parametricity points and to try to go into greater depth about the original question.

Comment: I was really confused at `∏ * (Λ a -> (a -> a))` until I realised that `*` here meant Haskell kind rather than product. @Vitus: Thank you for your comment about existential quantification and disjunction. This explains why some like to call sigma types dependent sums - even though I associate sums with coproducts.

Comment: @copumpkin: in your ninth paragraph you have "Because we don't have typecase, when we construct a value of type `forall a. B`, that does something different based on what a was instantiated to.", which doesn't grammar (or it does, but not in the way I think you meant). Otherwise a really good read :)

Answer (score 8):

To (attempt to) answer the actual question (which is less interesting than the answers to the broader issues raised), the question is ill formed because of a "type error"

```
Either ~ (+) 
(,)    ~ (*)
(->) b ~ flip (^)
()   ~ 1
Void ~ 0
```

These all map types to integers, and type constructors to functions on naturals. In a sense, you have a functor from the category of types to the category of naturals. In the other direction, you "forget" stuff, since the types preserve algebraic structure while the naturals throw it away. I.e. given `Either () ()` you can get a unique natural, but given that natural, you can get *many* types.

But this is different:

```
(forall r . (a -> r) -> r) ~ a
```

It maps a type to another type! It is not part of the above functor. It's just an isomorphism *within* the category of types.  So let's give that a different symbol, `<=>`

Now we have

```
(forall r . (a -> r) -> r) <=> a
```

Now you note that we can not only send types to nats and arrows to arrows, but also some isomorphisms to other isomorphisms:

```
(a, (b, c)) <=> ((a, b), c) ~ a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c
```

But something subtle is going on here. In a sense, the latter isomorphism on pairs is true *because* the algebraic identity is true. This is to say that the "isomorphism" in the latter simply means that the two types are equivalent under the image of our functor to the nats.

The former isomorphism we need to prove directly, which is where we start to get to the underlying question -- is given our functor to the nats, what does `forall r.` map to? But the answer is that `forall r.` is neither a type, nor a meaningful arrow between types.

By introducing forall, we have moved away from first order types. There's no reason to expect that forall *should* fit in our above Functor, and indeed, it doesn't.

So we can explore, as others have above, why the isomorphism holds (which is itself very interesting) -- but in doing so we've abandoned the algebraic core of the question. A question which can be answered, I think, is, given the category of higher-order types and constructors as arrows between them, what *is* there meaningful Functor to?

**Edit**:
So now I have another approach which shows why adding polymorphism makes things go nuts. We start by asking a simpler question -- does a given polymorphic type have zero or more than zero inhabitants? This is the [type inhabitation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inhabitation), and winds up being, via Curry-Howard, a problem in [modified realizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realizability), since it's the same thing as asking if a formula in some logic is realizable in an appropriate computational model. Now as that page explains, this is decidable in the simply typed lambda calculus but is PSPACE-complete. But once we move to anything more complicated, by adding polymorphism for example and going to System F, then it goes to undecidable!

So, if we can't decide if an arbitrary type is inhabited at all, then we *clearly* can't decide how *many* inhabitants it has!

Comment: Thanks.  This answer helps a lot, too.  I did intentionally overload the use of `~`, but you got the idea.  The part that really helped me was the treatment of the mapping as a functor.  Then when you say "What does `forall r.` map to?" I can clearly understand that the functor can't map that to an algebraic expression.

Comment: Well, you could conceivably construct a commutative semiring of types (with isomorphism as the equivalence relation) and interpret 0 and 1 as additive and multiplicative identities, respectively, instead of naturals.

Answer (score 4):

It's an interesting question. I don't have a full answer, but this was too long for a comment.

The type signature `(forall r. (a -> r) -> r)` can be expressed as me saying

> > For any type `r` that you care to name, if you give me a function that takes `a` and produces an `r`, then I will give you back an `r`.

Now, this has to work for *any* type `r`, but it can be a *specific* type `a`. So the way for me to pull of this neat trick is to have an `a` sitting around somewhere, that I feed to the function (which produces an `r` for me) and then I hand that `r` back to you.

But if I have an `a` sitting around, I could give it to you:

> > If you give me a 1, I'll give you an `a`.

which corresponds to the type signature `1 -> a` or simply `a`. By this informal argument we have

> > `(forall r. (a -> r) -> r) ~ a`

The next step would be to generate the corresponding algebraic expression, but I'm not clear on how the algebraic quantities interact with the universal quantification. We may need to wait for an expert!

Comment: Yeah, I understand the isomorphism, but the algebraic expression eludes me.  It is indeed equivalent to the expression being able to provide a term of type `a` to any function that requests it, with `id` being the trivial request.

Comment: Mmm, I realized as I was writing this that you might understand the isomorphism already. Still, it might be useful for anyone else who wanders through!

Answer (score 4):

A few links to the [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage):

- [Universal quantifier](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/universal+quantifier), corresponds to [dependent product](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/dependent+product).
- [Existential quantifier](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/existential+quantifier), corresponds to dependent sum (dependent coproduct).

---

Thus, in settings of category theory:

```
Type               | Modeled¹ as               | In category
-------------------+---------------------------+-------------
Unit               | Terminal object           | CCC
Bottom             | Initial object            |
Record             | Product                   |
Union              | Sum (coproduct)           |
Function           | Exponential               |
-------------------+---------------------------+-------------
Dependent product² | Right adjoint to pullback | LCCC
Dependent sum      | Left adjoint to pullback  |
```

¹) in appropriate category ─ [CCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category) for total and non-polymorphic subset of Haskell ([link](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~nad/publications/danielsson-popl2006-tr.pdf)), CPO for non-total traits of Haskell ([link](http://www.cs.gunma-u.ac.jp/~hamana/Papers/cpo.pdf)), [LCCC](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+cartesian+closed+category) for dependently typed languages.

²) `forall` quantification is a special case of dependent product:

```
∀(x :: *). y[x] ~ ∏(x : Set)y[x]
```

where `Set` is the [universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory#Universes) of all small types.